# Instagram images URL changes

Tags: instagram

From last week, we noticed that we are unable to access some of the full-resolution Instagram photographs of our customers that are normally hosted in Amazon AWS. We noticed that some are now hosted in a new URL (most likely owned by Facbeook), e.g. http://origincache-frc.fbcdn.net/1388803_545828265488033_5521543_s.jpg
But these are low-res thumbnails.

Where are the actual full-resolution photographs now stored?

We know that 2 months back there are some changes to the prefix of the image URL.
But now this seems to be a whole new location and possibly naming convention as well.

Please help.

Thanks

Jeff

Answer (score 1):

Change the last url part `_s.jpg` to `_n.jpg`, like the below:

- before: `http://origincache-frc.fbcdn.net/1388803_545828265488033_5521543_s.jpg`
- after: `http://origincache-frc.fbcdn.net/1388803_545828265488033_5521543_n.jpg`